# Working with an external JS script in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do some work with the containsLocation bit of the google maps JS API and I'm struggling to coordinate the function calls in react. In the js fiddle included (https://jsfiddle.net/4pearvsj/) everything works great and I plan on just rewriting the code a little to return either true or false if a set of given coordinates is located within the polygon.

The trouble I'm having is calling the

```
var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({})
```

function in my App.js file. I'm including the script in my index.html, but when I call the function in my App.js file I receive the error "cannot read property 'maps' of undefined". I am aware of the google-map-react package but I don't believe I can use the containsLocation features with this package. My question is how would I go about properly accessing this API within my react app without using the google-map-react package?

Comment: Why you don't use maps for react? https://dev.to/jessicabetts/how-to-use-google-maps-api-and-react-js-26c2

Comment: @GasparTeixeira I don't actually need a map displayed on my page and, as mentioned in my post, I don't believe I can reference the containsLocation feature through the maps for react package. Perhaps this is just my ignorance though

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to post your code here in this question? Checking the link you post looks like you want something different.

Comment: @GasparTeixeira I don't have any code written for this. I've deleted anything I've written for this behavior as it has not worked. The rest of the code from my project isn't relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the `X of undefined` error because on mount of the Application the code is running through once before google has initialized on the page.

You should wait for your application to mount before attempting to access google on the window, `componentDidMount()`, but also wrap the check to ensure it is ready.

In React you can still embed a script tag in your HTML Head which will match the fiddle and work as expected with the src + callback

Comment: The function call referencing the API is in my componentDidMount hook and "google" is still considered undefined within my function body